# SAN failover with Solaris 11 express

Tags: solaris, storage-area-network, iscsi, failover

Is there a good solution to provide failover between two identical servers based on Solaris 11 Express? We replicate data between the two SANs now, but want to setup a failover solution.

I have looked at IPMP as a alternative, but is not sure if it is a good solution when it is between two hosts? As the SAN2 is identical to SAN1 and communicates through iSCSI, a IP address change should be a working solution? It's most likely that the clients lose any active sessions, but it would be a minimal impact and downtime(?)

Comment: What is your architecture? Also, what are you trying to fail over? Do you have a database running on the servers? Or a custom app? NFS? Web server?

Comment: Virtual machines, Xen.
I added more information to my first thread.

Comment: Please get your terminology straight - it's not clear what you want and what you have.

Comment: Can we assume that Solaris 11 Express is your fileserver?

Comment: Is Nexenta high-availability an option?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for HA solutions based on Solaris then you probably *don't* want to go Solaris 11 Express. Even Oracle Solaris Cluster doesn't support Solaris 11 Express.

Stick with 10 unless there is a compelling, overriding need to go with 11.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rowley. There are features of ZFS we need to use, such as encryption, which is not supported in earlier versions unfortunately.